# Can't use a macro inside bracket or for trimming

Tags: macros, expansion, includegraphics

I'm trying to define figure optional parameters as a default with a user command but I can't use it inside the `[ ]`. The next example throws an exception when I replace the `trim=0 0 0 0` with `trim=\trim`.

```latex
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\trim}{0 0 0 0}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]{Figure}
        \caption{blablabla.}
    \end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

Besides, my objective is to define a command such as I can replace the whole sentence `width=\linewidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip` inside `[ ]` with it.

Comment: You have to expand `\trim` in `trim=\trim` before passing the whole option list to `\includegraphics`. Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555489/79060.

Comment: Since that optional argument is actually a complex list of arguments that doesn't parse when hidden. But if you *really* want to define the whole argument list, then why not define an alternative *command*? `\newcommand\trimgraphics{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip]}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*EDIT ON AUGUST 20, 2020*

*Once more I(Ulrich Diez) put myself into an embarrassing situation:*

*While writing the things below, I(Ulrich Diez) didn't think about the fact that square-brackets `[` and `]`—unlike curly braces—are not of category code 1 and 2 but are ordinary characters of category code 12 and that therefore square-brackets can occur within macro-arguments. Less complicated and much shorter than the code below is:*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand{\trim}{0 0 0 0}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\trim}{%
           \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=%
        },clip]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
        % Why two captions?
        \caption{Testing of the Y-axis.}%%%%%
        \caption{blablabla.}%%%%%
    \end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

The sequence

```
\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\trim}{%
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=%
},clip]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

triggers the following:

The `\expandafter`-chain leads to expanding `\trim`:

```
\exchange{0 0 0 0}{%
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=%
},clip]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

Expanding `\exchange` yields:

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=%
0 0 0 0,clip]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

*END OF EDIT ON AUGUST 20, 2020*

---

---

If the definition of the `\trim`-command can change from figure to figure, then you can, e.g., use the `\romannumeral0`-expansion- and argument-exchanging-technique—the gist of `\romannumeral0`-expansion is:

- TeX expands expandable tokens while gathering tokens that belong to the *⟨number⟩*-quantity that is to be represented in roman numerals.
- If the first token which TeX finds while gathering the *⟨number⟩*-quantity is a digit, e.g., `0`, then the process of gathering tokens that belong to the *⟨number⟩*-quantity turns into a process of gathering more digits or something that is not a digit and therefore terminates the process of gathering. Expandable tokens get expanded while gathering digits. A space-token terminating a digit-sequence terminates the process of gathering more digits and gets silently discarded.
- If the number gathered is not positive, TeX will silently swallow the tokens forming the *⟨number⟩*-quantity without delivering any token in return.

This implies that `\romannumeral` can be used for tricking TeX into doing a lot of expansion- and argument-exchanging-work as long as it is ensured that in the end a non-positive number is found.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand{\trim}{0 0 0 0}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[%
          \romannumeral0%
          \expandafter\exchange
          \expandafter{\trim}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
        ]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
        % Why two captions?
        \caption{Testing of the Y-axis.}%%%%%
        \caption{blablabla.}%%%%%
    \end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

---

The sequence

```
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\exchange
  \expandafter{\trim}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

triggers the following:

The process of obtaining the (top-level-)expansion of `\expandafter` triggers the process of delivering the top-level-expansion of the next but one token and terminates when the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the next but one token terminates. Thus:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggers the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the next but one token:
\includegraphics\expandafter[%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\exchange
  \expandafter{\trim}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

The next but one token outgoing from the first `\expandafter` is also an `\expandafter`, thus:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in 
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggers the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the next but one token:
[%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\exchange
  \expandafter{\trim}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

The next but one token outgoing from the second `\expandafter` is `\romannumeral`, thus:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in 
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in 
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral in progress;
  %   Sub-process of \romannumeral-expansion for gathering tokens of a <number>-
  %   quantity in progress:
  0%
  \expandafter\exchange
  \expandafter{\trim}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

TeX finds the digit `0`, thus `\romannumeral`'s sub-process of gathering tokens of a *⟨number⟩*-quantity turns into the process of gathering more digits or something that terminates the digit-sequence:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral in progress;
  %   Sub-process of \romannumeral-expansion for gathering more digits of a
  %   <number>-quantity in progress; digit "0" found so far:
  \expandafter\exchange
  \expandafter{\trim}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

While searching more tokens/digits belonging to the *⟨number⟩*-quantity, TeX encounters the third `\expandafter`:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral in progress;
  %   Sub-process of \romannumeral-expansion for gathering more digits of a
  %   <number>-quantity in progress; digit "0" found so far:
  %     Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the third \expandafter
  %     in progress, this process triggers the process of obtaining the top-
  %     level-expansion of the next but one token:
  \exchange
  \expandafter{\trim}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

The next but one token outgoing from the third `\expandafter` is `\expandafter`, thus:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral in progress;
  %   Sub-process of \romannumeral-expansion for gathering more digits of a
  %   <number>-quantity in progress; digit "0" found so far:
  %     Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the third \expandafter
  %     in progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-
  %     level-expansion of the fourth \expandafter:
  \exchange
  %   Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the fourth \expandafter
  %   in progress, this process triggers the process of obtaining the top-
  %   level-expansion of the next but one token:
  {\trim}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

The next but one token outgoing from the fourth `\expandafter` is `\trim`, thus the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the fourth `\expandafter` terminates when the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of `\trim` is terminates:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in 
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral in progress;
  %   Sub-process of \romannumeral-expansion for gathering more digits of a 
  %   <number>-quantity in progress, digit "0" found so far:
  %     Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the third \expandafter
  %     in progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-
  %     level-expansion of the fourth \expandafter:
  \exchange
  %  Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the fourth \expandafter
  %  terminated.
  {0 0 0 0}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

As the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the fourth `\expandafter` is terminated, the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the third `\expandafter` terminates, too:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral in progress;
  %   Sub-process of \romannumeral-expansion for gathering more digits of a
   %  <number>-quantity in progress, digit "0" found so far:
  %     Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the third \expandafter
  %     terminated.
  \exchange
  {0 0 0 0}{ width=\linewidth,trim=},clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

As the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the third `\expandafter` is terminated, `\romannumeral`-expansion continues, which yields expanding `\exchange`:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral in progress;
  %   Sub-process of \romannumeral-expansion for gathering more digits of a
  %   <number>-quantity in progress; digit "0" found so far:
  <space-token>width=\linewidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

TeX finds a space-token. That space-token terminates the sub-process of gathering more digits of a *⟨number⟩*-quantity and gets silently discarded.

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral in progress;
  %   Sub-process of \romannumeral-expansion for gathering more digits of a
  %   <number>-quantity terminated; number "0" found.
  width=\linewidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

As TeX found a *⟨number⟩*-quantity whose value is `0`, while `0` is not a positive value, the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of `\romannumeral` terminates by silently swallowing the tokens forming that *⟨number⟩*-quantity without TeX delivering any token in return.

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of \romannumeral:
[%
  % Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of \romannumeral terminated.
  width=\linewidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

As the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of `\romannumeral` is terminated, the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second `\expandafter` terminates, too:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter in
% progress, this process triggerd the process of obtaining the top-level-
% expansion of the second \expandafter:
\includegraphics
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second \expandafter
% terminated.
[%
  width=\linewidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```

As the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the second `\expandafter` is terminated, the process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the fiirst `\expandafter` terminates, too:

```
% Process of obtaining the top-level-expansion of the first \expandafter
% terminated.
\includegraphics
[%
  width=\linewidth,trim=0 0 0 0,clip%
]{/path/to/graphics/file.jpg}%%%%%
```