# How to define a part of style for \newminted?

Tags: minted

I'm trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand\mystyle{framerule=1pt,rulecolor=gray}
\newminted[foo]{text}{\mystyle,linenos,numbersep=2pt}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work. I need `\mystyle` to be present as an element among others. How can I do this?

Comment: `\mystyle` need to be expanded once before `\newminted` uses it. Something like `\expanded{\noexpand\newminted[foo]{text}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\mystyle},linenos,numbersep=2pt}}` does the trick.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ would be great if you can post it as an answer, please

Comment: I hesitate to add a answer since there's already many similar (and even more general) q&a on this site, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555489 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558926. Another approach is to add "style key (a key stands for other keys)" to `keyval` package.